# Any tips for using rclone quickly?

Tags: backup, cloud, dropbox

I hope this isn't too broad, but I'm was looking for a non-proprietary alternative to nautilus-dropbox and I discovered rclone. It's pretty neat on its surface and I can see some potential.

The command I run to sync my dropbox and local directory is

```
rclone sync -P ./ dropbox:/
```

And it takes a long time checking files that I haven't modified - even when I run this command twice in a row. The files that have changed are quickly identified and transferred quickly, but it seems to perform thousands of checks on other sub-directories and files that haven't changed.

I'm looking for some approaches to speed this up a bit. Barring that, is there another alternative to nautilus-dropbox on Ubuntu 19.10? Perhaps one available from the apt-repositories?

Comment: I use Rclone on and headlless server with success, this tool is very usefull and quite easy to handle. So. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I updated with the command that I use. Main thing is that it seems as though this is checking every file within my local directory when it should be able to skip based on modifcation time alone

Comment: `copy` command will be faster as it wont remove deleted files from dest. You could launch `copy` as usual sync demands and 'clean' your dropbox once a month (for example) with `sync`